# How to display users reputation

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a reputation like badges in my project that called `senior writer` and `junior writer`. User reputation based on the total number like that obtained.

I have 3 table:

Table post:

```
    id_post | news      | id_user
    3       | IT news   | 1 
    4       | game news | 2
```

Table user:

```
id_user | username
   1    | dora
   2    | boots
   3    | swipper
```

Table vote:

```
id_vote | id_post | id_user | LIKE
10      | 3       | 2       | 1
11      | 3       | 1       | 1
12      | 4       | 3       | 1
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT p.*, SUM(like) AS like_post, 
(SELECT SUM(like) //this is subquery start
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN post p ON p.id_user= u.id_user 
LEFT JOIN vote v ON  v.id_post=p.id_post GROUP BY u.id) AS reputation // end subquery 
FROM post p 
LEFT join user u ON p.id_user=u.id_user 
LEFT JOIN vote v ON p.id_post=v.id_post 
GROUP BY p.id_post 
ORDER BY p.id_post DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This is my view:

```
    <?php foreach $news as $data:?>
    <?php echo $data['id_post'];?>
    <?php echo $data['title'];?>
    LIKE: <?php echo $data['like_post']; ?>
    post by <?php echo $data['username'];?>
    reputation: <?php if ($data['reputation']==1)
    {echo "JUNIOR writer";} 
      else 
    {echo "SENIOR Writer"; }
    ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

My expectation user Dora will get reputation called `senior writer` because receive 2 LIKE. And boots will get reputation called `junior writer` because only receive 1 LIKE.

The problem is the return query is an error like this:
`Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Any answer?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.

```
SELECT u.id_user, u.username, SUM(v.like) AS reputation
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN post p ON u.id_user=p.id_user 
LEFT JOIN vote v ON v.id_post=p.id_post 
GROUP BY u.id_user
```

Use this php code.

```
LIKE: <?php echo $data['reputation']; ?>
    post by <?php echo $data['username'];?>
    reputation: <?php if ($data['reputation']==1)
    {echo "JUNIOR writer";} 
      else 
    {echo "SENIOR Writer"; }
    ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

EDIT:**

Query for `like_post`

```
SELECT v.id_user,v.id_post,SUM(v.like1) AS like_post
FROM vote v  
LEFT JOIN USER u ON v.id_user=u.id_user 
GROUP BY u.id_user
```

Query for `reputation`

```
SELECT u.id_user, u.username, SUM(v.like1) AS reputation
FROM USER u 
LEFT JOIN post n ON u.id_user=n.id_user 
LEFT JOIN vote v ON v.id_post=n.id_post 
GROUP BY u.id_user
```

Comment: In the post, i have 2 kind of `like`, total like post called `like_post` and total like user called `reputation` :)

Comment: what are the expected values of `like_post` and `reputation`?

Comment: `like_post` is just total like of the post... if `reputation` is total like that user receive calculate from all post. Lets say if user have 2 post. then post 1 have 2 likes and post 2 have 5 like. so the reputation of user will be 7 like. My problem is how to display that 7 likes of user.

Comment: then writing 2 queries will be wiser. 1 for `user` level `reputation` and 1 for `post` level `like_post`.